# How to reduce the width of UIButton from both left and right with animation?

Tags: ios, uibutton, uiviewanimation

I have tried to reduce the width of `UIButton` from  both left and right on clicking by using following code. But instead it just only shrinks the size of `UIButton`. The code is

```
    -(void)loginclickAction:(id)sender
{
        self.centerZoom = [CAKeyframeAnimation animationWithKeyPath:@"transform"];
        self.centerZoom.duration = 1.5f;
        self.centerZoom.values = @[[NSValue valueWithCATransform3D:CATransform3DMakeScale(1, 1, 1)],[NSValue valueWithCATransform3D:CATransform3DMakeScale(.9, .9, .9)],[NSValue valueWithCATransform3D:CATransform3DMakeScale(.8,.8, .8)],[NSValue valueWithCATransform3D:CATransform3DMakeScale(.7, .7, .7)],[NSValue valueWithCATransform3D:CATransform3DMakeScale(.6, .6, .6)],[NSValue valueWithCATransform3D:CATransform3DMakeScale(.5, .5,.5)]];
        self.centerZoom.timingFunction = [CAMediaTimingFunction functionWithName:kCAMediaTimingFunctionEaseOut];
        self.loginButton.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeScale(.5,.5);
         self.loginButton.alpha = 1;
        [self.loginButton.layer addAnimation:self.centerZoom forKey:@"buttonScale"];
        [self.loginButton setUserInteractionEnabled:NO];

}
```

But the output is shrinking of the `UIButton` which i don't want. Please help me to find the way in reducing the width of the button animated.

Comment: So you want to reduce the width but not the height? Are you expecting this to 'squash' the image or text on the button?

Comment: Yes, i wish to reduce only the width of button but not height and that too with animation. I should feel the width reduction :) @Wain

Comment: @Abbie have you tried below posted answer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your transforms are all affecting multiple dimensions:

```
CGAffineTransformMakeScale(.5, .5);
```

this is scaling the width (x) and height (y), to scale only the width:

```
CGAffineTransformMakeScale(.5, 1);
```

and the same applies to

```
CATransform3DMakeScale(.9, .9, .9)
```

which is changing x, y and z dimensions and should be

```
CATransform3DMakeScale(.9, 1, 1)
```

Answer (score 1):

You need a way by which you can scale the button only across the width.
Use below method which scales button horizontally from full width to half with animation-

```
-(void) reduceButtonWidthFromLeftAndRightWithAniamation:(UIButton *)button
{
    [UIView beginAnimations:@"ScaleButton" context:NULL];
    [UIView setAnimationDuration: 1.5f];
    button.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeScale(0.5, 1.0);
    [UIView commitAnimations];
}
```